# Why are Pig's job jars so big

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

When I execute a pig script through the PigServer java class, a lot of Jobxxx.jar's are being created. I understand these are the Map/Reduce jobs that are being sent to the Hadoop cluster.
Because I have a quite complex script I understand that this will be split up in a lot of different jobs.
I am confused, however, why these jar files have to be so big. Of course they all contain my UDF's code, which isn't so big, but they also contain for example the entire (exploded) org/apache/pig structure. The resulting jar files are over 7 MB each.

How can I prevent these files from becoming so big before I send them to the hadoop cluster?

Comment: I figure the reason reason it includes the org/apache/pig structure is because the Jobs can be compiled against different versions of Pig. For some projects I've worked on we have sent Pig 0.10 and 0.11 Jobs to the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The jobs are as big as they are for a number of reasons:

- as mr2ert said, the jobs can be compiled for different versions of Pig, the MR cluster doesn't really care;
- Pig is a client-side thing. The MR framework couldn't care less about what created the job, it needs a `.jar` to execute. Pig compiles the job, creating a `Mapper` / `Reducer` pair for each job implementing the features needed.

Now since Pig compiles the jobs on the client side and then submits the job jar to the cluster and since the cluster needs to have all dependencies in it's `CLASSPATH`, the most reasonable option is to create an exploded `.jar` with all the needed dependencies bundled.

As far as I know, there is nothing you can do to reduce the size because it's an engineering decision made by Pig's authors to bundle the dependencies when submitting the job.

And, frankly, if you have trouble handling 5 - 100 MB for the `.jar`, what the hell are you using Pig for anyway?

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. To answer your question, I really don't care the jobs are 7MB each, the problem is that there are ~80 of them per request. This alone is not a problem, if it wasn't for another issue, where the /tmp folder on my client does not get emptied, unless the jvm is shut down. Shutting it down is not really an option, since I run it in a application server.

Comment: Now the /tmp folder contains many GBs of jars after a few requests. The hadoop cluster is supposed to handle big data, not my client application server. I have solved the issue by deleting old jar files, in times that no request is running.